# Jooq combine a list of OR conditions to a condition with AND

Tags: java, jooq

I have a list of conditions which should be combined with OR

```
List<Condition> conditions; //conditionA, conditionB, ... other conditions
```

I have another condition

```
Condition dateCondition;
```

Now I want to combine as below

dateCondition AND (conditionA OR conditionB ...)

What would be a good way to do this.

Is there a Jooq function to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write

```
dateCondition.and(DSL.or(conditions))
```

The method you're looking for is [`DSL.or(Collection<? extends Condition>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#or-java.util.Collection-)